# No podspec found for `appcenter` in `../node_modules/appcenter/ios/appcenter.podspec`

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, visual-studio-app-center

Trying to install microsoft AppCenter on our react-native app and encounter the following issue

```
No podspec found for `appcenter` in `../node_modules/appcenter/ios/appcenter.podspec`
```

The version number is

```
"appcenter": "3.0.0",
```

The line in our podfile is

```
 pod 'appcenter', path: '../node_modules/appcenter/ios/appcenter.podspec'
```

Answer (score 8):

Turned out that it seems that they changed the `appcenter` name to `appcenter-core` but the corresponding name wasn't updated

```
pod 'appcenter-core', path: '../node_modules/appcenter/ios/appcenter-core.podspec'
```

resolved the issue